# Docking footers with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer, sticky-footer

Say I have the following "template" for what one of my pages should look like:

[image]

My pages consist of a header, a content section (different for each page), and a footer. Page height is the header height + content height + footer height. Notice the height of the footer; it's pretty tall/beefy. I'm OK with this.

I don't want a 'sticky' footer, instead I'm looking for the following functionality:

- If the header height + content height is greater than viewport/window height, I don't want the footer to be visible until the user scrolls down to it (normal footer behavior); but...
- If header height + content height + footer height is *less than* viewport/window height, I want the footer pinned down to the bottom of the viewport. Meaning if the content for a particular page is very small or is even coompletely empty, I want my header pinned to the top of the window, and the footer pinned to the bottom.

#### [Example in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ngrk9sz/2/)

What do I need to do to change my `footer` div to exhibit the desired behavior?

```
<!-- What needs to change here? -->
<div class="footer ">
    This should always be shown at the bottom if there isn't a lot of content to display below the header.
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a sticky footer is *exactly* what you want (just not a `fixed` footer)

Taken directly from the wiki for [sticky-footer](/questions/tagged/sticky-footer):

> Sticky Footer is a CSS technique used to anchor the footer section to the bottom of the page, regardless of the page's height. When the page height is less than the viewport, the Sticky Footer will be at the bottom of the viewport, and when the page height is longer than the viewport, the Sticky Footer will be at the bottom of the page.

Here's the canonical Sticky Footer Implementation:
http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/

Here's a bare bones example:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" ... />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <p>Your website content here.</p>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
.footer, .push {
  height: 4em;
}

.footer {
  background: yellow;
}
```

If you want to use bootstrap, just add the bootstrap CSS and whatever other classes you want

#### [Simple Demo in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z0SAUVx8xPvkvpmAkRRI?p=preview)

#### [Bootstrap Demo in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IgR7GCNvgtm7Km4Tx9B6?p=preview)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks @KyletMit (+1) - I guess I'm a bit surprised that Bootstrap doesn't offer this out of the box. In your Plunker example, in `style.css`, I don't the CSS that actually implements this "stickiness". **What code actually "sticks" the footer to the bottom of the window/viewport?** Thanks again!

Comment: The thing that *sticks* the footer is that `.wrapper` takes up 100% of the screen minus a fixed height for the footer, set via the `margin-bottom`.  Then the footer takes up exactly that height.  Bootstrap doesn't need to provide every web development trick in one library.  In fact, it needs to have a specific focus to prevent from becoming bloated.  If a tool already exists, it's perfectly fine to allow developers to continue using it rather than absorb it.

Comment: @smeeb - bootstrap doesn't offer sticky footers that are varible height, responsive tabs, 3 or more levels of navigation, and many many things out of the box, it's up to developers to extend the features they need rather than bloat a framework, framework by definition is the framework, not the finished building.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another simple solution

**HTML**

```
    <body>
    <header>
     ....
    </header>
    <div class="container" role="main">
     ....
    </div>
    <footer>
     ....
    </footer>
    </body>
```

**JS**

```
(function ($) {

        var height = $('footer').height();
        //update the  value when page is loaded
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').css({"margin-bottom" : height });

        });

        //update the  value when the browser is resized (useful for devices which switch from portrait to landscape)
        $(window).resize(function () {
        $('body').css({"margin-bottom" : height });
        });

    })(jQuery);
```

**CSS**

```
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
[role="main"] {
    padding-bottom:30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Schneider (+1) - please see my question underneath KyleMit's answer - I have the same question for you! Thanks again!